# How do I use multiple variables and strings within an os.system() command?

Tags: python, curl, os.system

im trying to make a simple program that downloads a file. im having a problem with the command part. here is the code:

```
import os

#gather user input
print("hello! welcome to the website dowloader! paste in the url(including the http 
part) and type in the file name!)")
url = input("website url: ")
filename = input("the filename:")

#the command i want run. for example, if the url was "https://example.com" and the 
#filename was "example.html"
#then i would want the command run to be: 'curl https://example.com --output 
#example.html'
cmd = str("curl ", url," --output ", filename)
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: `str("curl ", url," --output ", filename)` are you asking how to concatenate strings? You do that with the `+` operator, but usually, formatting strings would be eaiser here, so just `f"curl {url} --output {filename}"`. Also, you should probably be using `subprocess` instead of `os.system`

Comment: but also, why don't you just use Python to download the file instead of shelling out to curl?

Comment: I know, I was pointing that out trying to figure out what you **meant** by that. It is obviously incorrect, since it raises an error (probably should have posted that error in here btw)

Comment: are {} used to put variables into commands?

Comment: There are no "commands". That is a *sting*. its for *string formatting*, and yes, it does string interpolation

Comment: @WestinFrancis Look up "python f-string"

Comment: See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting

Comment: ok thank you so much. can you post that as an answer?(the one you posted first and then edited) so i can mark this as answered and so other people can see what the answer was without having to post their own question? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @WestinFrancis feel free to post it and accept your own answer, that is totally allowed!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> `str("curl ", url," --output ", filename)` are you asking how to concatenate strings? You do that with the `+` operator, but usually, formatting strings would be eaiser here, so just `f"curl {url} --output {filename}"`. Also, you should probably be using `subprocess` instead of `os.system`

Comment: This is a serious security risk. You should be advising the OP to use `shlex.quote()`.

Comment: And if you're adding someone else's comment as an answer, the polite thing to do is to click the "Community Wiki" link so you're not accepting credit for it under your own name.

Comment: (Think about what happens if a URL is given as `https://example.com/$(rm -rf ~)/` -- you don't want `rm` to be invoked by the shell, deleting all your files; that's part of the reason the original comment advised using `subprocess.Popen` instead, as with its default `shell=False` configuration it doesn't start a shell, avoiding that risk).

Comment: ...that is to say, f/e, `subprocess.run(['curl', url, '--output', filename])` f/e doesn't start any shell at all, nor need one, because it's doing the work of generating an argv list ready to be handed to the OS kernel on its own. (If you set made it `subprocess.run(['curl', '--fail', '--output', filename, url], check=True)` you'd get an exception thrown if curl didn't succeed).

Comment: i would have said the same myself